# Retrofit parsing json array without key

Tags: android, json, retrofit

NOT DUPLICATE, I TRY DID LIKE IN THAT POST, NOT WORK

Sorry for my English. I use retrofit in my android application, and I have some problem with JSON, I try parsing JSON like this:

```
[
 {
  "FIELDS": {
     "ID": "21"
   },
   "PROS": []
 },
{
  "FIELDS": {
     "ID": "21"
   },
   "PROS": []
 }
]
```

this is my object:

```
public class In_Catalog {

    @SerializedName("FIELDS")
    FIELDS FIELDS;

    public In_Catalog.FIELDS getFIELDS() {
        return FIELDS;
    }

    public void setFIELDS(In_Catalog.FIELDS FIELDS) {
        this.FIELDS = FIELDS;
    }

public class FIELDS {
String ID;
 public String getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public void setID(String ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
}
```

This is my interface

```
Observable<List<In_Catalog>> getProductsInCatalog(@Query("section") int id_selection);
```

I cant parse JSON, my `FIELDS` object is always NULL. What I do wrong?

Comment: it not DUBLICATE it different, and i try did like in that post.

Comment: I solved your question. please refer this http://notes.io/mg3R

Comment: @NiravJoshi thanks for answer! Now i try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ResultDTO {

@SerializedName("FIELDS")
private com.universal.jainconnection.data.FIELDS mFIELDS;
@SerializedName("PROS")
private List<Object> mPROS;
}


public class FIELDS {

@SerializedName("ID")
private String mID;
}
```

> replace this

```
Observable<List<ResultDTO >> getProductsInCatalog(@Query("section") int id_selection);
```